# matplotlib changes the color of BRG in every layer

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I'm encountered a problem. I'm trying to show a BGR, blue layer, green layer, and red layer Using OpenCV and matplotlib.

I know that OpenCV reads an image as BGR and matplotlib reads an image as RGB, therefore I converted the RGB to BGR first and managed to print the original picture but when I tried to print blue layer, green layer, and red layer and turned out the color of each layer is still unconverted.`

```
    import cv2 as cv
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

    img = cv.imread('baboon.png')

    bgr = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

    B = bgr [: ,: ,0]
    G = bgr [: ,: ,1]
    R = bgr [: ,: ,2]

   plt.subplot (2, 2, 1)
   plt.imshow (bgr)
   plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
   plt.title('BGR')

   plt.subplot (2 , 2, 2)
   plt.imshow (B)
   plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
   plt.title('Blue Layer')

   plt.subplot (2 , 2, 3)
   plt.imshow (G)
   plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
   plt.title('Green Layer')

   plt.subplot (2 , 2, 4)
   plt.imshow (R)
   plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
   plt.title('red layer')
   plt.show ()
```

The result of the code

[image]

why it looks like unconverted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're plotting the single-channel data [with a colormap](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) that's not a greyscale ramp.

Add a suitable `cmap=` parameter to each `.imshow()`, e.g.

```
plt.imshow(G, cmap=plt.get_cmap("Greys"))
```

## Example

As discussed in the comments, OP wants to show each channel with a colormap related to the channel.

You can use `LinearSegmentedColormap` to generate these. I've also taken the liberty of replacing the repetitive code with a loop.

```
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

img = cv.imread("lenna.png")

bgr = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

B = bgr[:, :, 0]
G = bgr[:, :, 1]
R = bgr[:, :, 2]
b_map = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("B", ["#000", "#00f"])
g_map = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("G", ["#000", "#0f0"])
r_map = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("R", ["#000", "#f00"])

for i, (title, matrix, cmap) in enumerate([
    ("BGR", bgr, None),
    ("Blue", B, b_map),
    ("Green", G, g_map),
    ("Red", R, r_map),
], 1):
    plt.subplot(2, 2, i)
    plt.imshow(matrix, cmap=cmap)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.title(title)

plt.show()
```

The output is

[image: output example]

## Extended example

Here's an example that shows the HSV and YCbCr results too. (Getting those YCbCr color ramps was a thing or two...)

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap

# Build color ramps in YCbCr space
filler = np.full(255, 128)
ramp = np.linspace(0, 255, 255)
ch0_ramp = np.rot90(np.dstack((ramp, filler, filler))).astype("uint8")
ch1_ramp = np.rot90(np.dstack((filler, ramp, filler))).astype("uint8")
ch2_ramp = np.rot90(np.dstack((filler, filler, ramp))).astype("uint8")
y_ramp = 1 - (cv.cvtColor(ch0_ramp, cv.COLOR_YCrCb2RGB)[:, 0] / 255)
cr_ramp = cv.cvtColor(ch1_ramp, cv.COLOR_YCrCb2RGB)[:, 0] / 255
cb_ramp = cv.cvtColor(ch2_ramp, cv.COLOR_YCrCb2RGB)[:, 0] / 255

# Build color maps
b_map = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("B", ["#000", "#00f"])
g_map = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("G", ["#000", "#0f0"])
r_map = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("R", ["#000", "#f00"])
h_map = get_cmap("hsv")
s_map = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("S", ["#888", "#0f0"])
v_map = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("V", ["#000", "#fff"])
y_map = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("Y", y_ramp)
cr_map = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("Cr", cr_ramp)
cb_map = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("Cb", cb_ramp)

# Load material

bgr = cv.imread("lenna.png")
rgb = cv.cvtColor(bgr, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
hsv = cv.cvtColor(bgr, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
ycc = cv.cvtColor(bgr, cv.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)

# Draw all the things!
for i, (title, matrix, cmap) in enumerate(
    [
        ("BGR", rgb, None),
        ("Red", rgb[:, :, 0], r_map),
        ("Green", rgb[:, :, 1], g_map),
        ("Blue", rgb[:, :, 2], b_map),
        ("Hue", hsv[:, :, 0], h_map),
        ("Sat", hsv[:, :, 1], s_map),
        ("Val", hsv[:, :, 2], v_map),
        ("Y", ycc[:, :, 0], y_map),
        ("Cr", ycc[:, :, 1], cr_map),
        ("Cb", ycc[:, :, 2], cb_map),
    ],
    0,
):
    plt.subplot(4, 3, 1 + i + (2 if i else 0))
    plt.imshow(matrix, cmap=cmap)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.title(title)

plt.show()
```

The output is

[image]

Comment: but why it should be a grey-scale ramp? is it because it will converted to 1 and 0? for example in blue layer, everything in blue turns out white or 1.

Comment: The thing is the RGB channels themselves don't really have a "redness" or "greenness" or "blueness" to them, they're just greyscale. You need to either pad them back to BGR (leaving the other channels zero) or use a colormap with the channel's own ramp.

Comment: what if in YCbCr or HSV channels? is it work the same as RGB? I tried `cmap=plt.get_cmap("Greys")` to each `.imshow()` but it seems the result isn't right.

Comment: @AmandaKamphoff You'd have to figure out what a suitable perceptual colormap is for HSV (how would you represent the change of saturation? Gray to "just some color"?); for YCbCr you can get some inspiration from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#/media/File:Barn-yuv.png

Comment: @AmandaKamphoff I bit the bullet and added the HSV and YCbCr examples too :)

Answer (score 0):

When you are separating the three B/G/R channels, you are converting a 3-channel image to a single channel image best represented by a gray-scale image.

You need to add `cmap='gray'` to imshow to make it look like real gray-scale image.

```
plt.subplot (2, 2, 1)
plt.imshow (bgr)
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.title('BGR')

plt.subplot (2 , 2, 2)
plt.imshow (B, cmap= 'gray')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.title('Blue Layer')

plt.subplot (2 , 2, 3)
plt.imshow (G, cmap= 'gray')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.title('Green Layer')

plt.subplot (2 , 2, 4)
plt.imshow (R, cmap= 'gray')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.title('red layer')
plt.show ()
```

[image]

Look at the color of nose in right two images. The red nose is represented by white in red layer but not so in blue layer because nose pixel value is 0 in blue layer i.e. black.
The color of channel will take the value near 1 on 0-1 scale and 255 on 0-255 scale in the separated channel images. This 1 is represented by WHITE in gray-scale images.

If you really want to see Blue/Red/Green instead - use cmap like below:

```
plt.subplot (2, 2, 1)
plt.imshow (bgr)
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.title('BGR')

plt.subplot (2 , 2, 2)
plt.imshow (B, cmap= 'Blues')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.title('Blue Layer')

plt.subplot (2 , 2, 3)
plt.imshow (G, cmap= 'Greens')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.title('Green Layer')

plt.subplot (2 , 2, 4)
plt.imshow (R, cmap= 'Reds')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.title('red layer')
plt.show ()
```

[image]

Comment: Those are white-to-color maps, which are the inverse of what OP wants...

Comment: at first this line `bgr = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR)` isn't necessary but when I tried to run, the color of bgr variable was't the original color. then based on stack overflow answer somewhere (I don't remember the question) it says "OpenCV reads an image as BGR and matplotlib reads an image as RGB" therefore I added that line and the result is the same as the original